# Get the name of the class in a Singleton method

Tags: ruby, singleton

I want a class to return its own name, pluralized, using e.g. "active_support/inflector":

```
describe "self.resource" do
  it "should be databases" do
    Database.resource.should equal "databases"
  end
end

class Database
  def self.resource
    self.class.to_s.tableize
  end
end
```

This fails with:

```
   expected #<String:84017460> => "databases"
        got #<String:84018030> => "classes"
```

How can I access the name of the class a singleton method is being called on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
class Database
  def self.resource
    to_s.tableize
  end
end
```

The problem is you call `to_s` on the class `Database` belongs to, and it's `Class` class. You should call `to_s` on local `self` instead, which is `Database` itself. Since `self` is default receiver of the message, it's okay to leave simply `to_s.tableize`.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't call `class` method on `self`. Singleton class already belongs to the class, not the instance.

In your case:

```
self.to_s.tableize
```

should work as intended.